# html HR line getting cut by css absolute+relative positioning

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, css-position

Here is my HTML code-

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="/static/theme.css" rel="Stylesheet" />  
</head>
<body>
<div id="footer">
<hr>Copyright content goes here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

content of theme.css is

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    color: #f00;

}
```

when I view the HTML, I see that HR line is available (width of line) only till the content "Copyright content goes here". I need to make sure that copyright content is available at the very bottom only so I'm using absolute+relative CSS.

When I change position to relative, it works fine- I see full HR line.

why is absolute+relative positioning "cutting" the HR line?

Comment: To answer the question you literally asked ("why"), it's because absolute-positioned elements have no position in the flow, and hence no natural way to determine their width from outside.  Hence, they shrink to the size of their content, and since HRs don't have any content...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add width:100% to footer style.

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    color: #f00;
    width:100%;
}
```